# C# ASP.NET MVC display attribute (prompt via Resources.resx) file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Properties.Resources), Prompt = "What should be here?")]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Properties.ResourcesDataAnnotations), ErrorMessageResourceName = "IDRequired")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]{9}", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Properties.ResourcesDataAnnotations), ErrorMessageResourceName = "IDNotValid")]
        public override string ID { get => base.ID; set => base.ID = value; }
```

How can I set prompt via Resources.resx file?

Comment: If the `ResourceType = typeof(Properties.Resources)` then set the `Prompt` property value to a resource name. For example, `Prompt = "IdPrompt"` where `IdPrompt` is public static string property with the name _IdPrompt_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Jackdaw mentioned in comments just use

```
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Properties.Resources), Prompt = "IDPrompt")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Properties.ResourcesDataAnnotations), ErrorMessageResourceName = "IDRequired")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]{9}", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Properties.ResourcesDataAnnotations), ErrorMessageResourceName = "IDNotValid")]
    public override string ID { get => base.ID; set => base.ID = value; }
```

Where IDPrompt is static string name in Resources.resx file.